# How to created nested JSON request in REACTJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am trying to take value from Employee ID field and add it to object property employee: {id:} in JSON. Other elements in JSON is working just fine, it's the nested element that I am not able to figure out.

This for an application to submit timecard for employees. Back end if written in java. I have the APIs written and tested. Just trying to write some UI code now with React.

```
import { Component } from "react";
import {Form, Row, Col, Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
import axios from 'axios';

class TimeCard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            date : '',
            in : '',
            out : '',
            **employee : {
                id : ''**
            }
        }
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({[e.target.name] : e.target.value});}

    async SubmitTime (e) {
        console.log(this.state);
        let response = axios.post('http://.../timecard/add', this.state);        
        console.log(response);
        console.log("this is executed");
    }

    render () {
        const {date, timein, out, **employee**} = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
            <br></br>
            <h2 className="display-6">Daily Timecard</h2>
            <Form>
            <br></br>
                <Row>
                    <div className = 'col-xs-4'>
                        <Col>
                            <**Form.Control onChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)}  type = 'text' placeholder = 'Employee ID' name = 'id' value = {employee.id} />**
                        </Col>
                    </div>                     
                </Row>
                <br></br>
                <Row>
                <div className = 'col-xs-4'>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Control onChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)} type = 'date' name = 'date' value = {date} />
                        </Col>
                    </div>
                </Row>
                <br></br>
                <Row>
                    <div className = 'col-xs-4'>
                        <Col>
                            Time In <Form.Control onChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)} type = 'time' name = 'in' value = {timein} />
                        </Col>
                    </div>
                    <div className = 'col-xs-4'>
                        <Col>
                            Time Out <Form.Control onChange = {this.handleChange.bind(this)} type = 'time' name = 'out'  value = {out}/>
                        </Col>
                    </div> 
                                        
                </Row>
                <br></br>
                <Row>
                <div>
                        <Col>
                            <Button onClick = {this.SubmitTime.bind(this)} >Submit Timecard</Button>
                        </Col>
                    </div>

                </Row>
            </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TimeCard;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destructure the nested property `id` from `employee` as below.

```
const {date, timein, out, employee: { id } } = this.state;
```